# facebook graph api how to add <br> tag

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i use url links to post to my facebook page through my facebook app
but when the post shows up it does not brake in order to be shown like this:

hello from around
the world

it shows up like this

hello from around
the world!

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=pageid|token.1-609481694|104294482966963|-SzbaghgDgCur4JPx3C5AQxDLj8&message=hello%20from%20around
the%20world!%20:)&method=post

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try `%0A`. It was working in Graph API some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, but have you tried adding in a [CRLF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) pair? URL-encoded, that would be `%0d0a`, so that would make your URL be

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=pageid|token.1-609481694|104294482966963|-SzbaghgDgCur4JPx3C5AQxDLj8&message=hello%20from%20around%0d0athe%20world!%20:)&method=post

Logically, I think that *should* work, but I haven't tried it.